# update og:image on jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i Update the og:image on Jquery autocomplete selection? I tried several ways but it doesn't seems to be working.

Below is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="assets/css/gfx/skold.png" />

    <script>

        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
            "Apple iPhone 5",
             "Nokia Lumia 920",
             "Samsung Galaxy S5",
             "Sony XZperia Z"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
            $('meta[name=og\\:image]').attr('content', 'http://www.isellmobile.co.uk/images_webdev/logos/ISellLogo.jpg');
        });

       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: og:image will be read from a server that does not use javascript.

Comment: @matthew Are you trying to say that it's not possible to change it using Jquery at client side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the jQuery UI autocomplete widget.  You need a listener on the autocomplete change event.
See the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

Something like this:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                $('meta[name=og\\:image]').attr('content', 'http://www.isellmobile.co.uk/images_webdev/logos/ISellLogo.jpg');
            }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's correct! I am using jquery autocomplete here. Was wondering is it actually possible to change it dynamically at client side anyways? Reason why is I couldn't get it working even on doc load event?

Comment: It's possible to change the attribute value on the client.  Quickest way to test is in the browser console window (F12 in most).

Why are you trying to change this on the client?  The values in these tags are usually used in the initial page request and should be rendered from the server.